# Why can I access the whole JSON object but not not sub sections of it?

Tags: javascript, json

Requesting data from the mapbox API I can print the whole JSON object to the console but when I try and print some of the "sub objects" I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" error.

In Chrome dev tools I can print out the sub object fine.

```
var suggestedLocationsReturn = $.get("https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=MY_API_KEY", 'json');
```

This prints the object fine

```
console.log(suggestedLocationsReturn);
```

This throws the error

```
console.log(suggestedLocationsReturn.responseJSON.features[0].place_name);
```

But running the above line in the Chrome dev tools console displays the data as expected.

Comment: Probably because it's just a string and you didn't parse into JSON.

Comment: two hints: the return is a wrapper, not data. the console is async.

Comment: You need to wait for the response.